# Не могу сконвертировать из командной строки в параметры ydl_opts для youtube_dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Я хочу использовать youtube_dl внутри кода на python. В командной строке я использую это так: `"youtube-dl --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args "-ss 00:01:00.00 -to 00:02:00.00" -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc7I-i7sPrg""`

Как я могу перевести это для Python:

```
ydl_opts = {

}

with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.run(
            ['ffmpeg', '-i', f'{os.getcwd()}/files/{filename}.mp4', '-ss',
             f'{start}', '-to', f'{end}',
             f'{os.getcwd()}/files/{filename}_{timestamp}_cut.mp4'])
```